# Can I transfer location from my GPS receiver to a Nikon camera via Bluetooth?

Tags: metadata, gps, bluetooth

Is it possible to send location information (lat. and lon.) from a Bluetooth-equipped Garmin GPSMAP 64ST GPS receiver to a Bluetooth-quipped Nikon camera?  If so, how?

Thanks for the “track, time” suggestion for finding the location of a shot.  I have used this method and it does work, but is time consuming and tedious.  Since the GPS and the camera has blue tooth capability I hoped for a simpler method to log location.  The Garmin website does show a method to log information on a Nikon camera via two cameras that I may try in the future.

Comment: What many people do is recording their track (specialized devices, or smartphone with suitable app), the export the track to a GPX or KML file, and on their PC run a utility that tags the picture with the location from the track, using the picture recording time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Nikon cameras with Bluetooth do not operate as a bluetooth master. It is there to enable Nikon's Snapbridge automatically configure wireless communication with a Snapbridge app on a smartphone or tablet.